# How to convert PCIe3 to PCIe2 using a PCI adapter

Tags: motherboard, pci-express, sound-card, pci

I have a new HP Z2 G9 workstation featuring the following expansion slots:

```
1 PCIe 3 x4 (x16 connector); 1 PCIe 3 x4 (x4 connector); 1 M.2 2230 PCIe 3 x1; 1 M.2 2280 PCIe 4 x4; 1 M.2 2280 PCIe 3 x4; 1 PCIe 3 x1 (x4 connector); 1 PCIe 4 x16 (x16 connector)
```

I want to use an old Vx442e Digigram audio card, which requires PCIe2 expansion slot, in the new workstation. I found a PCI to PCI express adapter on Amazon, will this work? Or do I need some other type of PCI adapter to accomplish this?

Comment: You shouldn’t need an adapter to use a PCIe 2 device in a PCIe3 slot since PCIe standard has backwards compatibility. A PCI to PCI Express adapter will not work. **PCI is an entirely different standard and predates both PCIe2 and PCIe3 by probably a decade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCI is backwards compatible, no adapter needed.

So long as there are enough channels (literally, the card isn't longer than the slot, and even that is negotiable sometimes) you can plug an older gen (lower version number) peripheral into a newer PCI slot without issue.